# managing multiple rsa keys (git, web server)

Tags: git, ssh, rsa

I’m learning how to use git and GitHub.  When I ‘git push origin master’, it prompts me to enter my GitHub user and pass combo.  So setting up an ssh key would make my life easier and more convenient.  The guide I’m using is actually a udemy course by a teacher named Jason Taylor.  The course is behind a pay wall so I can’t really share the specific video. The module I’m on recommends entering this command:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "[$user]@gmail.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/gnull/.ssh/id_rsa): 
/home/[$user]/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? n
$
```

Most other students in Jason Taylor’s udemy course would press ‘y’.  It’s a no brainer. But for me, I’ve already have an id_rsa file with a key in it for my web server.  So If I enter, ‘y’, I’ll revoke rsa access to my web server.  Amiright?

How do I preserve ssh key access to my web server AND establish an ssh key connection to GitHub?

Here are the contents of my .ssh directory located in my home folder:

```
$ ls
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts 
$
```

Comment: Do you really need a different key for github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When searching Google for ‘managing multiple rsa keys’, among the top hits is this(1) stack overflow post.  That post teaches how to add and manage multiple rsa keys which isn’t necessary for me as **@Roman** pointed out in his comment.  I found an official doc(2) on GitHub  which explains that you can simply copy your existing private or public key (like the one I’ve already established for my web server) to my clipboard and then simply add it to GitHub.  Then according to another GitHub doc(3), you can test your ssh connection by attempting to ssh to GitHub.  Here is the command:

> $ ssh -T git@github.com

Which when I entered it, returned this:

> Hi [$username]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Yay! That worked.  My key is set up properly. But I noticed that

> $ git push origin master

...still prompts me for my GitHub credentials. I kind soul in #github on the FreeNode network on irc recommended I try:

> $ git remote -v

Which returned this:

> origin https://github.com/[$username]/[$project-name].git (fetch)
>       origin https://github.com/[$username]/[$project-name].git (push)

Notice ‘https://’?  That’s the problem here.  The solution:

> $ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:[$username]/[$project-name].git

Now, finally, when I invoke,

> $ git push origin master

...it pushes my local changes up to GitHub without prompting me for my user name and pass.

(1): http:// stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client 
  (2): https:// help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/ 
  (3): https:// help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/

Please note: stackoverflow wouldn't let me post more than two hyperlinks which is why I formated three of them unconventionally.

Answer (score 0):

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/gnull/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

In this step, you can input different file to save your ssh key pairs.

And in your ~/.ssh/config, you can specify the key file(identifyFile) for each host(server).

[Here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-multiple-ssh-identities-for-gitbash-mac-osx-linux-271943168.html) is a good tutorial for multiple SSH identities.